# LPWSTR string to bool?

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a variable of type `LPWSTR` which contains `"true"` or `"false"` in it. 
Is there a way I can convert that to a variable of type bool with `true` or `false`?

Ideally I want to do something like this:

```
FooClas::MyMethod()
{
    LPWSTR  variableOne;
    bool    variableTwo;
    MyMethodOne(&variableOne);

    // At this point, variableOne can be either "true" or "false".
    // Do something to check if "true", then variableTwo = true, otherwise variableTwo = false.
}
```

Comment: Look up [wcscmp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strcmp-wcscmp-mbscmp?view=vs-2019)

Comment: Didn't know about this... still learning c++. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the precondition, that `variableOne` points at either `"true"` or `"false"`, the most efficient way to turn that into a boolean value would be:

```cpp
bool const variableTwo { *variableOne == L't' };
```

It's enough to test for a single discriminating property, like the first character. Any other character, or even the length of the string would equally suffice.

Answer (score 3):

`std::wistringstream` could help:

```
std::wistringstream(variableOne) >> std::boolalpha >> variableTwo;
```

Header file:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
```